# react-native-vision-camera in react native 0.71.1 showing CameraView is not fabric compatible yet

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am using react-native-vision-camera in rn-0.71.1, there I used the code from example app provided in that repo. When opening the camera it is showing CameraView is not fabric supported yet.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `android\gradle.properties` update the following property from `true` to `false`

`newArchEnabled=false`

Dont forget to do gradle clean and recreate the build.
I hope this will help :)